# Selecting from table A using grouped/sorted data from table B

Tags: mysql

Basically what I need to do is find trending pages. I have one table that holds a list of page IDs and the timestamp of creation (they are created when a person visits the aforementioned page).

```
SELECT * FROM trends WHERE timestamp > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) GROUP BY pageId ORDER BY  COUNT(id) DESC
```

This will return the pageId in trending order, but now I need to use those pageIds to select from another table (one that contains the actual pages).

I could use a php `while($row = fetch array)` loop to select rows from the other table, but I'd like to do all of this in only one query.

I am not sure of the syntax needed to do that however...

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the two tables `trend` and `pages` on the `pageId`. See the [MySQL reference for the `JOIN` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html).

Comment: Was my immediate thought when I saw this question posted on twitter. Something like this, I think?

SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
 tbl_of_actual_pages INNER JOIN trends ON tbl_of_actual_pages.page_Id=trends.tbl_of_actual_pages
WHERE 
 trends.timestamp > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY 
 tbl_of_actual_pages.pageId 
ORDER BY 
 COUNT(id) DESC